# Glyphicon showing on new line

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

**[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/tIynq6WFft)**

Note: that I customized my bootstrap menu. Code is below. I need the glyphicon to be next to "book", but it breaks to the next line in small resolution.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="">    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-header-sm">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="assets/images/logo_sm.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>

    <!-- <div class="text-center"> -->
      <p class="navbar-text">book</a></p>
    <!-- </div> --> 

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
      <li>
         <a href="#" class="toggle-transparent tof">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
           <span class="navbar-title">Table of Contents</span>
         </a>
       </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-header-sm {
  @media(min-width: @screen-sm-max){

    display: none;
  }
}

.navbar-header-sm {
  @media(max-width: @screen-sm-max){

    float: left;
  }
}

.navbar-header {
  @media(max-width: @screen-sm-max){

    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: I would advise putting this into a jsfiddle.net, much easier for people to edit and provide a solution. Nevermind, BeatAlex already put it in Bootply!

Comment: Or at least have a image of the problem

Comment: Not sure if this will help with your problem but your component alignment is off in your navbar instead of pull-right you should be using navbar-right. See http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: @DavidCorbin Here is the image of the problem. As you can see the glyphicon breaks to the next line in iPhone res.   http://imgur.com/3AjIdSW

Comment: I'm currently testing the mobile stackexchange app and don't have access to a computer but I'd recommend Bootswatch if it would suit your needs http://bootswatch.com/

Comment: In your bootplay example, you are not aplying float:left to your -navbar-header-sm when small screen (under 768px). Pobably that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can simply embed the glyphicon link in the p tag:

```
    <!-- <div class="text-center"> -->
      <p class="navbar-text"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="assets/images/logo_sm.png" alt=""></a>book</a></p>
    <!-- </div> -->
```